# Calling methods defined in different parts of the directory to wherever you want

Tags: oop, go, interface

I am struggling with calling a function defined and implemented in a different package to my main file. This here is a replica of the structure of the codebase I am working on.

in **repo/collegeutil/handlecourse.go**

, I have

```
package collegeutil

func (clg *CollegeUtil) AddCourse(ctc context.Context, param1 string, param2 string) {
    #Function implementation 
}
```

CollegeUtil is a struct defined in **repo/collegeutil/student.go**. In this file, I have

```
package collegeutil

type CollegeUtil struct {
   subSvc college.subjectService
}
```

And in a different file, that is in **repo/college/student.go**, I have

```
package college

type subjectService interface {
   AddCourse(ctx context.Context, param1 string, param2 string)
}
```

Now in my **repo/classes/main.go**, I have the following

```
package main

reply, err := college.subjectService.AddCourse(ctx, param1 string, param2 string)
```

But this is not working. I’m getting an error that says **too few arguments to call to college.subjectService.AddCourse**. But the number of arguments is correct. Apparently it requires one more parameter in the beginning which is of college.subjectService value in argument. What is this actually? ?

I also tried **collegeutil.CollegeUtil.AddCourse()**. But here I get **“can not call pointer method AddCourse on collegeutil.CollegeUtil”**

What is the correct way of calling AddCourse method to the main in the above codebase?

Comment: Can you explain “not working”? Compile time / run time? What errors are generated?

Comment: @jdizzle when I typed college.subjectService.AddCourse(), I am getting “too few arguments in call to college.subjectService.AddCourse. But the number of arguments is correct.

Comment: When I did collegeutil.CollegeUtil.AddCourse(), can not call pointer method add missing ledger on collegeutil.CollegeUtil

Comment: I wonder if it even compiles? Because in `collegeutil/student.go` you wrote you have a `subSvc` field of type `college.subjectService` but `subjectService` is un-exported .. is this just a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could see a few unexported items in your code sample. Try exporting them first and build..

Export `subSvc`:

```
package collegeutil

type CollegeUtil struct {
   SubSvc college.subjectService
}
```

Eport `subjectService`:

```
package college

type SubjectService interface {
   AddCourse(ctx context.Context, param1 string, param2 string)
}
```

And:

```
reply, err := college.SubjectService.AddCourse(ctx, param1 string, param2 string)
```

This is not a solution; since I don't have rough reputation to comment, adding here.